# Podcasts in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, podcasting

We would like to use Microsoft Teams and SharePoint Online to push out podcasts (both video and audio only).

Does anybody have any guidance on using Microsoft Teams (third party add-ons) and SharePoint Online within Microsoft Teams to communicate out podcast media?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/portal-get-started) would be my choice for a repository of recordings and management of permissions. These can then again be distributed as links in Teams and in SharePoint.

There is also mobile apps that lets you save media for offline viewing if that is a requirement.

Comment: This was our initial choice but Stream is not yet rolled out in our organization.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint online, one option is to put each podcast MP3 file into a powerpoint file, export the powerpoint file as an MP4 file, publish the MP4 files to Office365 Stream, teach our users how to use Stream (online and offline). Or you can use 3rd party Podcast tools.

Reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-as-podcast-platform/m-p/16636