# Uploading multiple audio files to a page on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages

I'm struggling to do what I think should be simple and easy: We want to display *multiple* audio files on a Page in a clean and elegant way. The audio clips are all uploaded to our Documents library.

The Embed and File Viewer web parts only displays 1 audio file at a time, and it ends up looking like a video. They also show the menu bar (Share, Copy Link, Download, etc.) at the top, which I'm also trying to figure out how to remove too.

[image: Embedding an audio file using the Embed web part]

There was [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/278919/91475) posted about uploading the audio files to a PowerPoint > exporting the ppt to mp4 > uploading to Streams, but the mp4 just has all the audio clips playing back-to-back. Not to mention, it takes forever to export to mp4 (there are easier ways to render a video like this anyway).

I'm interested in [following the first reply to this question here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mp3-audio-file-on-sharepoint-online-page/703dfa72-7885-44fb-8019-6f4cd511c790), but we use SharePoint Online exclusively—I'm not familiar with using custom or external web parts/scripts. We are hesitant to do this as we want to keep things as simple as possible, but if this is the best method then we'll explore this.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way you can try to use the Modern script editor. It is a custom web part in github and can work like the script editor in classic experience. You can fallow this [tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing) to install it.

You can embed the audio with [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

Works like below

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I've followed everything in your tutorial, but got stuck at step 7+. The Modern Script Editor does not show up when I go to edit a page and add a web part. In App Catalog, the app is Deployed but not Tenant Deployed. The App says it's already been added to the site. It is Active under Site Features. Is there something else I need to look at? I'm wondering if my cdn path could be wrong -- would that affect it? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Solved it. In src/webparts/scriptEditor/ScriptEditorWebPart.manifest.json, I had to set `requiresCustomScript` to `false`.  
For reference: [see this](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1188#issuecomment-369323523). In case anyone wonders, I'd also set `includeClientSideAssets` to `true` (in the package-solution.json file) to save from any headaches about the cdn path, but this wasn't the cause of my issue.

Comment: @chophop Thanks for your sharing and update. I am glad to hear you get the job done.